# Assign the counter number for object name

Tags: vb.net

I have 60 textboxes in vb and I want to export all of them into one text file. I use this code to do that:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("Filename.txt", TextBox1.Text)
```

Because I have 60 textboxes so I will take me a long time to do that, I use the **For...Next** to ease the procedure. I want to have a code like this:

```
For i as integer = 1 to 60
   My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("Filename.txt", TextBox(i).Text)
Next
```

Can I do that in vb? Are there any alternative ways to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of textboxes and add all the needed textboxes to the list. Use foreach loop on the list to access the textboxes one by one and use their text property as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the TextBoxes, **in order** using [Controls.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
    Dim fileName As String = "c:\some folder\path\Filename.txt"
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName)
        Dim tb As TextBox
        Dim matches() As Control
        For i As Integer = 1 To 60
            matches = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, True)
            If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
                tb = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
                sw.WriteLine(tb.Text)
            End If
        Next
    End Using
```

If you simply iterate over the Controls collection the TextBoxes may be returned in a different order (than their name) if you had cut them or copied/pasted some of them when you created the form.

Comment: Tks for answer! But I got the problem that it doesn't write anything to text file!

Comment: The code works fine for me.  Either you're getting an exception attempting to write the file and you're ignoring it, or none of the TextBoxes are being found because you have a different naming scheme.